# App Pools for Service Apps

Tags: sharepoint-server, service-application, application-pool

How would one go about choosing which Service Apps should go in what App Pool,
is there any logic to it?

1. One for search
2. one for MMD
3. one for Viso and Excel
   etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you really.  The only significant reason to split each service into its own app pool is so you can run each as a different user for security reasons.
The main reason to consolidate (other than simplicity) is to make more efficient use of server resources by reducing the number of app pools competing for memory.

Edit:  for each app pool you're looking at over ~800MB of RAM (IIS, .NET runtime, SharePoint libraries and infrastructure)

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, its depend upon your server hardware and usage of the service application.
As per MSFT, they recommend Max 10 App pool per web server including both( Web application and Service Application). an extra app pool put extra load on the server (CPU and Memory utilization). an highly active app pool can easily consume the 10GB of memory.

logic is simple.

- check your hardware on the server where you trying to configure these services.
- Examine the usage of your application.
- if the server also Web Front end role then also count the web application app pool usage.
- I would put all the low usage service application in under one app pool and larger within own app pool i.e. search.

the only advantage with dedicate app pool is, if something goes wrong then it will impact only that service application.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft guidance is one Application Pool for Service Applications and one for Web Applications. This minimizes memory usage and startup times.